# Legacy MessageCard doesn't work in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I tried creating my messagecard (legacy twitter JSON payload i tried) in Microsoft Teams, but it's not working. I failed to find any documentation on the same.

Update: Here's the test payload that i tried,

```
 {
  "themeColor": "0078D7",
  "sections": [
    {
      "activityTitle": "**Elon Musk**",
      "activitySubtle": "@elonmusk - 9/12/2016 at 5:33pm",
      "activityImage": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/782474226020200448/zDo-gAo0.jpg",
      "activityText": "Climate change explained in comic book form by xkcd xkcd.com/1732"
    },
    {
      "activityTitle": "**Mark Knopfler**",
      "activitySubtitle": "@MarkKnopfler - 9/12/2016 at 1:12pm",
      "activityImage": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000221985528/b2ebfafca6fd7b565fdf3bf4ccdb4dc9.jpeg",
      "activityText": "Mark Knopfler features on B.B King's all-star album of Blues greats, released on this day in 2005..."
    }
  ]
}
```

So i have the following questions:

- Does it worked for anyone else?
- Is legacy messagecard is supported?
- Share the documentation (if its available)

Comment: (1) Can you share the messagecard/JSON payload for analysis? (2) Try the same payload in Card Playground and see if it works. Here's the link - https://messagecardplayground.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tsang, Thanks for the payload.

I tested your above payload with Message card play ground and see the following card - it's working:

[image]

Being said that, i found a typo in the payload (it should be activitySubtitle, rather it was activitySubtle). Here's the updated payload:

```
"themeColor": "0078D7",
"sections": [
    {
        "activityTitle": "**Elon Musk**",
        "activitySubtitle": "@elonmusk - 9/12/2016 at 5:33pm",
        "activityImage": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/782474226020200448/zDo-gAo0.jpg",
        "activityText": "Climate change explained in comic book form by xkcd xkcd.com/1732"
    },
    {
        "activityTitle": "**Mark Knopfler**",
        "activitySubtitle": "@MarkKnopfler - 9/12/2016 at 1:12pm",
        "activityImage": "https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/378800000221985528/b2ebfafca6fd7b565fdf3bf4ccdb4dc9.jpeg",
        "activityText": "Mark Knopfler features on B.B King's all-star album of Blues greats, released on this day in 2005..."
    }
]
```

Now the updated card looks like:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Dev. Appreciate your detailed answer & steps in messagecardplayground.